# Problems with XLConnect library

Tags: r

I'm getting the following error when trying to load the XLConnect library.

```
library(XLConnect)
```

Gives me the following error:
Error: package ‘XLConnectJars’ 0.2.12 was found, but == 0.2.13 is required by ‘XLConnect’

How do I fix this problem?

I have tried:

```
update.packages("XLConnect")
install.packages("XLConnect")
```

Comment: XLConnectJars is a separate package--did you try reinstalling that separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XLConnect is twitchy and has some special needs, one of them is the package:
`‘XLConnectJars’` if you have a copy, it is too old. You need to update it, either using `install.packages("XLConnectJars")` or by using Tools>check for updates in RStudio.

You will also need to verify that you have Java 1.6...properly and fully installed. Once you do those two things, I think this error will disipate

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. :) I did have one issue to note for others. I had the excel file in an old 2003 format. This format caused an error but when converted to the newer .xlsx format the read function worked.